# "It might be considered risky"

Tags: grammar, word-choice

People might think that something is risky. Eg. burning the fire close to a forest. Then is it proper to say "It might be considered risky" or "It might be found risky"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Finding" something is about learning something new. "We found that it was risky to light a fire close to the forest when the fire nearly set light to one of the trees"

You didn't know that it was risky, then you tried it, and you learnt that it was risky.

If it what people already think, then you can say that they "considered it to be risky"

> It might be considered risky to light a fire in the forest, but if proper precautions are made the danger can be minimized.

It might be better just to use simpler language:

> Many people think that it is risky to light a fire in the forest...

Take care to chose the right word between "risk" and "danger".  Jumping of a cliff is dangerous, but not risky.

Comment: Yes, you find something after you study it. Not before.